# form to delete file asp

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I have inherited a system which allows user to see reports from various section and then leave them there for up to 1 year (the server deletes them on it's own) or go ahead and delete individual files if they prefer. The problem is that currently the way it is done the user has to click on each individual file and confirm deletion. I would prefer to have this setup as a form so that they can check the box next to each file they wish to delete and then confirm the list to be deleted and all will be done at once.

I'm drawing a blank though when it comes to how to execute this. I've currently set it up so that the file name is the value for each checkbox. I'm thinking this can be used with the javascript alert to confirm deletion as well as when processing the delete process.

```
<form>
<%
    Dim sMasterFolder
    Dim oMasterFolder
    Dim oFSO
    sMasterFolder=Server.MapPath(Session("HOMEFOLDER")+"/reports")
    Set oFSO=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    ' ** CHECK TO SEE IF ANY FILES ARE TO BE DELETED **
    If Request("sDel")<>"" Then
        oFSO.DeleteFile (Request("sDel"))
    End If
%>

<div class="section_heading_2">
    File Name
</div>

<%
    Set oMasterFolder=oFSO.getFolder(sMasterFolder)
    'Response.Write sMasterFolder & "<br /><br />"

    For each File in oMasterFolder.Files
        'Response.Write "<a href=delfile.asp?sDel=" & (replace(File.Path," ","%20")) &" onclick=""return confirmdelete()"">" & File.Name & "</a><br />"
        Response.Write "<input type='checkbox' value='" & File.Path & File.Name & "'> " & File.Name & "<br />"
    Next

    Set oMasterFolder = nothing
    Set oFSO = nothing
%>
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Delete">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume you just the "confirm action" function. If that is the case you could do a little old school JS.

**Head**

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
      function popupConfirmMsg(msg) {
      document.your_returnValue = confirm(msg)
      }
   </script>
```

**Button**

And then change your button to the following:

```
<input name="button" type="submit" id="button" onclick="popupConfirmMsg('Are you sure you want to do this?');return document.your_returnValue" value="Next" />
```

That should prompt the user to confirm the action. If they click on Cancel it will just close the popup box. If they click on OK then it will execute the POST. The only real downside to this is if they have JavaScript turned off in their browser settings, but most people have this on nowadays as HTML5/CSS/jQuery wouldn't work properly without it!

Comment: I ended up using what you provided and adding more to it so that it would list the files the user is confirming the delete for. As well as adding a select/unselect all function. I still have some changes I want to make so that it is more modular but this is much closer and actually functional now. Thank you. I realize this code doesn't work on jsfiddle but I figure you may like to see what I've changed. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZY4Yy/)